# Modelling relationsip between time series variables - R

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, trend

I have the below time series data. I want to model the relationship between the variables using R.

```
period  y       x
201501  1530    2.49
201502  1450    2.62
201503  1637    2.77
201504  1404    2.84
201505  1442    2.82
201506  1442    2.89
201507  1518    2.88
201508  1492    3.05
201509  1743    3.21
201510  1902    3.14
201511  1855    3.07
201512  1879    3.12
201601  2018    3.21
201602  2117    3.15
201603  2002    3.09
201604  1837    3.04
201605  1902    3.14
201606  1910    3.12
201607  2162    3.16
201608  2183    3.17
201609  2100    3.17
201610  2122    3.28
201611  2461    3.51
201612  2250    3.73
201701  2466    4
201702  2212    3.93
201703  2424    3.93
201704  2477    3.91
201705  2402    3.82
201706  2360    3.77
201707  2475    3.81
201708  2690    3.76
201709  2655    3.7
201710  2889    3.92
201711  2683    4.15
201712  2674    4.12
201801  2695    4.03
201802  2707    4.04
201803  2728    4.15
201804  2607    4.33
201805  2917    4.71
201806  2946    4.94
201807  3031    5.08
201808  3224    6.2
201809  3962    6.76
201810  4043    6.25
201811  3805    5.76
201812  3607    5.67
201901  3694    5.74
201902  3566    5.63
201903  3541    5.83
201904  3350    6.15
```

•   Y is the dependent variable.

•   Y is the price of a product, and x is the exchange rate.

•   I just want to estimate y at time t. For this reason previous lags of y, and previus lags of x and current value of x( value of x at time t) can be used.

Namely,       Y=f(yt-1, yt-2,......., xt, xt-1,xt-2......)

•   Existence of seasonality is suspected for y.

I am confused about modelling the relationship.

I guess,

1. First, I have to decompose seasonality and trend.
2. Then, for the trend first take the logs of the data and then take the differences of the logs to make them stationarity.
3. After, I have to start to model the trend.

But I am not sure about the above process and how to continue.

I will be very glad for any.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: what's the objective?

Comment: Making some simulations for future. For example, If exchange rate, takes value x(t+1) at t+1 time, what will be product's price at time t+1.  Also for  t+2, t+3,....

Comment: why does exchange matter? is this an imported product? do you have forecast of exchange rates?

Comment: I don't have forecasted exchange rate. Indeed, it is not my interest. I just want to know, if exchange rate takes some values, what will be product's price. Product's price is matter for me. I know that it is very closely related to the exchage rate.

Comment: The reason I'm asking about the problem setup is that there are methodological issues such as unit roots and endogeneoty that complicate the task. If this is all you have, then just run a simple regression $y \sim x$ $and be done with it.

Comment: Without taking any logs and differences? And also, doesn't making simple regression with lags of dependent variable?

Comment: @Aksakal, I am confused about time series analysis. Why isn't stationarity required in this situation? I will be very glad for a little explanation or a recomandation for any kind of source(book, article,..). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a simple regression $y_t\sim x_t$ or maybe even better $y_t\sim x_{t-1}$. The reason is that before trying anything fancy you need to address multiple methodological issues. So, instead, I'm suggesting to do this in the simplest way and be done with it.

For instance, what if the exchange rate is not the independent variable, but rather a dependent variable? This would actually make a sense from economics point of view: exchange rates can be a reaction to inflation. If the prices in one country are rising, and you believe in purchasing parity relationship then exchange rate will adjust to restore the parity. The prices (inflation) are determinants of the nominal interest rates, which are in turn determinants of exchange rate, e.g. through carry trade arbitrage.

I'm saying if you're not willing to deal with this sort of issues, then why not run the simple model?

On stationarity: if you run a formal unit root test on exchange rates they will probably show non stationary. However, why would they be non-stationary? The prices often are nonstationary, and you could look at the log returns of prices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving your time. I am not sure about stationarity. If, we look at to the trend of the price(y) alone, It has an increasing trend, due to inflation(or exchange rate- ı guess, change of exchange rate creates inflation). So, the expected value of y at anytime is not constant, which disturbs the constant mean assumption of stationarity. But, if we extract effect of x from y, we may obtain statinary series I guess. But I am not an expert about time series analysis.  So, I have some clues about the analysis. This annoys me.